# Is the function theta : P(Z) -> P(Z) defined as theta(X) = X(bar) bijective? If so, what is its inverse?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

No idea how to even approach this question. Does it mean to say that all the elements in set  X give out X(bar)? So, all the values in set X are our x coordinates and all the elements in X(bar) are our y-coordinates?

A push in the right direction plus a general idea on how to go about this problem will highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline X$ (or "X(bar)" in your notation)?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I was unsure of where to find the symbol while typing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assuming that by $P(Z)$ you are denoting the power set of $Z$ and by "X (bar)" you mean the complement of $X$ in $Z$, usually written $\bar X$ notice that $\bar {\bar X}=X$ and see if this helps.

Comment: Yes, the P does denote power set according to the symbol given in the book. I do not know of any other meaning of bar other than complement, so I am also assuming that they were referring to complement in the book. 

So, is it that the inverse of X(complement) will be X. So, when we plug it into function theta, we will get X back and the function is bijective?

Comment: Yup so the function is it's own inverse.

Comment: ok great! so, is my logic concluding that the function is bijective is correct? Further, how do I write show in my answer that "the function is its own inverse"? 

Thanks a lot for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

To prove $\theta$ is bijective we need to show $\theta$ is injective and surjective.

Suppose $\theta(A) \neq \theta(B)$ for some $A, B \in \mathbb{Z} $.

$\theta(A) = \overline{A} = \mathbb{Z} - A$, the set of all integers except for the ones in $A$.

$\theta(B) = \overline{B} = \mathbb{Z} - B$, the set of all integers except for the ones in $B$.

Since the two sets are unequal, then the set of integers excluded from the $\mathbb{Z}$ to form both the sets must also be unequal. Therefore, $A \ne B$. Hence, $\theta$ is injective.

To show $\theta$ is surjective, suppose $\theta: \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})} \to \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$. Suppose $T \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$, where $T$ is a set of all integers except for a few, $z_1, z_2, ..., z_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $S$ represent these integers, so $S=\{z_1, z_2,...,z_n\} \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$. But $\theta(S) = \overline{S} = \mathbb{Z} - S = T$. Therefore, for a $T \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$ there exists an $S \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$ for which $\theta(S)=T$. So, $\theta$ is surjective.

Since we have shown $\theta$ is both injective and surjective so it is bijective. Hence, there exists an inverse for this function.

In order to find the inverse, we need to find the function $\theta'$ such that $\theta'(\theta(X)) = X$.

$\theta'(\theta(X)) = X$

$\theta'(\overline{X}) = X$

$\theta'(\mathbb{Z}-X) = X$

Observe that $\mathbb{Z}-(\mathbb{Z}-X)=X$, so $\theta'(\mathbb{Z}-X)=\mathbb{Z}-(\mathbb{Z}-X)=X$.

So, $\theta'(Y)=\mathbb{Z}-Y=\overline{Y}$. Which makese sense because, $\theta(X)$ is a set of all integers except for the ones in $X$. Its inverse is the set of the missing integers $X$ and can be obtained by taking a complement on the result of $\theta(X)$.

Comment: I don't think the questioner specified that Z is the set of integers. Anyway, my question is on how to show that the complement operation (viewed as a function from the power set of a set S to the power set of S) is bijective. Some suggested using the fact that the complement of the complement is the original set. This seems like it is on the right track but I don't see the whole proof. If complement(A)=complement(B), then their complements must be equal? Is that what to say. Meaning complement(complement(A))= complement(complement(A)) but this means A=B right? This shows 1-1, I guess.